# How to use a Tokio Mutex within a sync and async context?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am using a trait from a [third party library](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_core/ecma/visit/trait.FoldWith.html) which does not support async methods.

My state is behind an `Arc<tokio::sync::Mutex<T>>` and I need to use it within the context of this library.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
  state: Arc<tokio::sync::Mutex<usize>>
}

impl Fold for MyStruct {
  fn fold_xyz(&self, node: Node) {
    let state = self.state.blocking_lock();
  }
}
```

Where the struct is called by the library

```rust
async fn fold_thing(state: Arc<Mutex<usize>>) {
  let mut my_struct = MyStruct { state };

  let result = library.globals.set(move || {
    target.fold_with(&mut my_struct)
  }}
}
```

I tried calling `state.blocking_lock()` however that results in the error:

```
Cannot block the current thread from within a runtime. This happens because 
a function attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being
used to drive asynchronous tasks
```

I don't fully understand why this error is occuring, is it because the the mutex is being used in a closure within an `async` function?

Or is that because the internals of the third party library also use an async runtime of their own?

Comment: use `spawn_blocking` to spawn blocking operations from an asynchronous runtime. `set` when it has to wait and *block* for a `Mutex` **is** a blocking operation.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how your two snippets interact, one defines a `fold_xyz` method, the other calls `fold_with` on an undefined `target` of unknown type, please [edit] your question add a [mre].